# Problems with printbibliography

Tags: bibtex, luatex

I'm currently writing a paper for my studies and am using a template made by an other student.

When I print the bibliography with the command

```
\printbibliography[nottype=online,heading=bibintoc,title={\langde{Literaturverzeichnis}\langen{Bibliography}}]
```

, the compiler gives me the following error:
[image]

`\langen` and `\langde` are two commands that have been specified to switch between english and german, currently the german command is executed (and works in *every* other usage of it. Though, I still get the error when I remove the commands altogether there.

[image]

How do I resolve this problem?

This should be a minimal version of the main.tex file.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}

\newif\ifde
\newif\ifen

\input{src/skripte/meta}

\newcommand{\langde}[1]{%
    \ifde\selectlanguage{ngerman}#1\fi}
\newcommand{\langen}[1]{%
    \ifen\selectlanguage{english}#1\fi}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=4cm, right=2cm, top=4cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[capposition=bottom]{floatrow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{footnote}

\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ext-authoryear-ibid,    maxcitenames=3,        maxbibnames=999,
    mergedate=false,
    date=iso,
    seconds=true,    urldate=iso,
    innamebeforetitle,
    dashed=false,
    autocite=footnote,
    doi=false,
    useprefix=true,    mincrossrefs = 1
]{biblatex}
\input{src/skripte/modsBiblatex2018}

\addbibresource{src/literatur/literatur.bib}

\AtBeginBibliography{\singlespacing}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is the logfile created by LuaLatex.

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)  (format=lualatex 2023.5.10)  17 MAY 2023 19:31
 system commands enabled.
**/data/thesis_main.tex
(/data/thesis_main.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / initializatio
n
Lua module: lualibs 2020-02-02 2.70 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2020-02-02 2.70 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / logging
Lua module: luaotfload-parsers 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / filelist
Lua module: luaotfload-configuration 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / conf
ig file reader
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /var/lib/texmf/luatex-cache/generic-
dev/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2020-01-26.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader
-2020-01-26.lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 3
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 4
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.11”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Lua module: luaotfload-loaders 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / callback h
andling
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-database 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / database
Lua module: luaotfload-unicode 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / Unicode he
lpers
Lua module: luaotfload-colors 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 5
Lua module: luaotfload-resolvers 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / resolver
s
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /var/lib/texmf/luatex-cache/generic-
dev/names.
Lua module: luaotfload-features 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / features
Lua module: luaotfload-letterspace 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-embolden 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-notdef 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-auxiliary 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / auxiliar
y functions
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-fallback 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / fallback
Lua module: luaotfload-multiscript 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / multis
cript
Lua module: luaotfload-script 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / Script help
ers
Lua module: luaotfload-tounicode 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / tounicod
e
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
. L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
Package: scrkbase 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent ba
sics and keyval usage)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
Package: scrbase 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package: scrlfile 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty
Package: tocbasic 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip47
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box45
)
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `toc'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `toc' on input line 137.
Package scrartcl Info: You've used standard option `12pt'.
(scrartcl)             This is correct!
(scrartcl)             Internally I'm using `fontsize=12pt'.
(scrartcl)             If you'd like to set the option with \KOMAoptions,
(scrartcl)             you'd have to use `fontsize=12pt' there
(scrartcl)             instead of `12pt', too.
Class scrartcl Info: You've used standard option `oneside'.
(scrartcl)           This is correct!
(scrartcl)           Internally I'm using `twoside=false'.
(scrartcl)           If you'd like to set the option with \KOMAoptions,
(scrartcl)           you'd have to use `twoside=false' there
(scrartcl)           instead of `oneside', too.
Class scrartcl Info: File `scrsize12pt.clo' used to setup font sizes on input li
ne 2212.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize12pt.clo
File: scrsize12pt.clo 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt)

luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /var/lib/texmf/luatex-cache/ge
neric-dev/names/luaotfload-names.luc)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package: typearea 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip48
\ta@div=\count163
Package typearea Info: You've used standard option `oneside'.
(typearea)             This is correct!
(typearea)             Internally I'm using `twoside=false'.
(typearea)             If you'd like to set the option with \KOMAoptions,
(typearea)             you'd have to use `twoside=false' there
(typearea)             instead of `oneside', too.
\ta@hblk=\skip49
\ta@vblk=\skip50
\ta@temp=\skip51
\footheight=\skip52
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 12
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 448.13095pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 2.4185pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 2.4185pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 635.5pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -41.72441pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 18.125pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 21.75pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 12.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 50.75pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 14.5pt
(typearea)              on input line 1719.
)
\c@part=\count164
\c@section=\count165
\c@subsection=\count166
\c@subsubsection=\count167
\c@paragraph=\count168
\c@subparagraph=\count169
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip53
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\section on input line 4723.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\section on input line 4723.
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip54
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=false'
(scrartcl)           for `\part on input line 4731.
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip55
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subsection on input line 4741.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subsection on input line 4741.
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip56
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subsubsection on input line 4751.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subsubsection on input line 4751.
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip57
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\paragraph on input line 4761.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\paragraph on input line 4761.
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip58
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subparagraph on input line 4771.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subparagraph on input line 4771.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip59
\belowcaptionskip=\skip60
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box46
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lof'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lof' on input line 6002.
\scr@dte@figure@maxnumwidth=\skip61
\c@figure=\count170
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lot'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lot' on input line 6014.
\scr@dte@table@maxnumwidth=\skip62
\c@table=\count171

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'thesis_main.bbl' found.

(./thesis_main.bbl
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.27       }
          
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.27       }
          
End of file on the terminal!
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! We likely need more information to be able to reproduce this issue, images of logs are likely not sufficient, could you edit in some code that produces that error please?

Comment: The line I sent with the initial request is the line producing the error. I'm not that good at debugging LaTeX, what could you need? The preamble of the document?

Comment: guess would be you have a bib entry with a `_` that is forcing a math mode error

Comment: In the citation label or in the title of the document? Or anywhere in the entry?

Comment: ideally you should show a _complete_ small document with the error

Comment: Most of the project is „outsourced“ in other files, but I can add an image of the main.tex file.

Comment: images are no help, you are asking people to debug your code, you should supply code, and  the error message as text

Comment: the problem is in the biblography so you can probably make an example with just `\begin{document} \nocite{*}` and some bibliography setup

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added a minimum example. At least that should be the minimum that still works with the compiler. I'm really sorry, but I don't know if you'd need anything else to be able to help me.

Comment: we can not run the example, but I would avoid `\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}` unless you have very specific legacy requirements, it disables a lot of luatex.  But the error is the file `src/skripte/meta.tex` that you have not shown uses your local command `\detrue`  without defining it (presumably the original intended definition was `\newif\ifde`

Comment: `bib` files are not tex `\include{src/literatur/literatur.bib}` could never work, bib files are read by bibtex or biber, not tex

Comment: About the \newif\ifde: It seems that I accidentally deleted the if…
About the import: Oh, I fixed that and updated the logfile.

Comment: sorry I give up, you have not provided any code related to the error.  which  is most likely in the bib file, also if  `\input{src/skripte/modsBiblatex2018}` is not needed to show the problem, delete it from the example so people can run it. If it is needed to show the problem, then it _is_ the problem and you should show it so someone can correct it